# aws alternative console/management web ui (stop/start/create/list)

Tags: amazon-web-services, console

Been searching for the last few days for an **alternative to the AWS Console Web ui**.

We want to give this to our employees to manage their development/test environment their self without interaction from the IT team.

What we want is an **extra Web ui** that does the following "**management tasks**"

- List all instances (maybe based on tags)
- Stop / Start instances
- Create / Destroy instances (from specific AMI's)

Also we would like to have logs + authentication (preferable LDAP)

I found a few but none of them actually was that simple.
We would also prefer to have a django/python based application but sinatra is also fine.

Alternatives that I found:

- Asgard from netflix
- Spurios (has no EC2 instances)

We also found Flask app builder to build our own app but it would be nice if some things already exsists. I believe many company's want the same but are they keeping that for internal use only ?

Maybe you know more projects that I, for some reason, did not stumble on.

Comment: Did u find any solution to this ?